# Android Image Sizing

Tags: android

I am trying to make a tile game that has 6 tiles in each row.  The tiles are a fixed size, 80x80 and fit snuggly on a 480x854 screen (since 6*80=480).  I am trying to make sure that my application works for other densities/sizes, but the logic is confusing to me.  What is the best way that I can be sure I handle other densities correctly?  I've read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html entirely, but am still confused.  Even if I scale images for different densities, can't I still run into the problem that the screen won't have enough pixels to support my "6 tiles in a row"? As an example, let's say the device was 320x480, but also high density.  No scaling would be done, and my 480px wouldn't fit on the 320px screen.  I am trying to not hardcode for pixels, but don't see another option.  Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided that I don't think there is an intended way to solve this problem.  I will have to rely on the fact that there are only a few screen sizes right now and make a "best fit" for the common sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `ImageViews`, you just need to make sure the images are large enough that they don't get blurred on larger screens and then set the correct scale type for each `ImageView`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType

Android should handle the rest for you.

Comment: So let me describe a simple case:  I have a 480x854 screen and design a 480x854px image for the screen.  Let's say that the screen is also high density and that I have my images in the high density folder.  Now, my application is opened on a high density screen that is 480x800.  Are you saying that will correctly scale it down?  I thought it only scaled in terms of density.

Comment: Also, I am not using an ImageView.  I am making a game so I draw the bitmap directly to the canvas.